# Filter out items that belong to the Source Packages

Tags: ubuntu, package-management, coreutils

Here I have a [Manifest of Ubuntu](http://releases.ubuntu.com/18.10/ubuntu-18.10-desktop-amd64.manifest)

I would like to list out only the Source Packages and not the containing items.

```
binutils    2.31.1-6ubuntu1
binutils-common:amd64   2.31.1-6ubuntu1
binutils-x86-64-linux-gnu   2.31.1-6ubuntu1
```

The result I would like to see:

```
binutils    2.31.1-6ubuntu1
```

Additionally, short information about each source package would be as well a nice thing.

```
binutils    2.31.1-6ubuntu1  The GNU Binutils are a collection of binary tools.
```

What are the most simple ways to achieve this using Bash, GNU Coreutils anything else?

Comment: I don't have an Ubuntu system at-hand, but aren't those individual, separate (if related) packages?

Comment: These are not containing items. These are packages. Actually in Ubuntu, a package depends on multiple other packages. So, they are separate package on which binutils depends. These packages are separated since they may satisfy dependency of some other packages too.

Comment: Hmm, it could be that I'm wrong, look at the manifest I linked. But they all belong to the same binutils, as they start with binutils-*. I kind of need help to rephrase my question. If they are seperate packages, but related to one another, then how should I call them?

Comment: The term you’re looking for is probably “source package”. The three listed `binutils` packages all come from [the `binutils` source package](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/binutils).

Comment: That is probably it, official definition of the Source Package: https://wiki.debian.org/Packaging/SourcePackage

Comment: The last part of your question is troublesome because descriptions are attached to binary packages, not source packages. There’s no good heuristic (IMO) for picking one of the descriptions in source packages with multiple binary packages...